# html code that executes wsh code through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wsh

I'm stuck on this code...I'm trying to get the html page to, when you click the link, call the bms function, which should open internet explorer, go to google, and fill the search textbox with the word "test".  This isn't exactly the website or word I want to use, but I needed to change it since the actual website/words are sensitive information. I want to use this through IE since our processes go through this browswer, specific with also using the -nomerge function. My code is below. Thanks for the help!

```
<html>
<head>    
<script>
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
function BMS()
{
WshShell.Run("iexplore.exe -nomerge http://google.com");
WScript.Sleep (5000);
WshShell.SendKeys ("test");
WScript.Quit();
}
</script>
</head>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:BMS();">BMS</a>
<br /><br />
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:DAY();">DAY</a>
</html>​
```

Comment: you dont need to prefix the onclick value with javascript, but I'm not sure that it'd hurt anything... though you seem to've missed the body tag. So, what I would do will be something like my answer... incoming

Comment: Is the text entry a real requirement? Why not add a query string to the URL to match what Google's form would submit?

Comment: I dont actually need a query to a search engine, I just did that because I cant put in sensitive info, so I changed the script around a bit. I'm looking for a method I could edit/use, not the actual going to google to type "test"

Answer (score 0):

Dont be thrown off by jade; it's just quicker. Just note I'm placing scripts just before the closing body tag.

```
html
  head
    title foo
  body // body tag added
    p notice that i've not declared script yet. Preference/good practice.
    a#bsdTrigger(href='#') foo    
    a#ssddTrigger(href='#') bar
    //- scripte here
```

#### The Important-ish part: [here's a pen](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/1ecb716c2fc9fe53eb7f2adb0717e8e7)

```
 (function() {
    // now the variable will not pollute your global ns
    var WshShell = {}; //ignore the OR only because there is no Active thing

    WshShell.log = function() { // fake behavior for testing
        console.log(arguments);
    } 

    var bsd = function BSD() {
        WshShell.log("foo");
        window.alert('foo!');
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById("bsdTrigger").addEventListener('click', bsd);
})();
```

**I hope this helps... It's very generic and contrived, but you'd employ the exact same methods in doing what you're trying to do.**

Comment: I dont know what happened to the "here's a pen" link, but its not working anymore and I can't view anything, nor can I get this code working.  How did you get it again?